# Android-How to develop applications for all phone devices or for majority of phones Concepts and techniques

Tags: android

Android-How to develop applications for all phone devices(Different screen sizes) or for majority of phones
Concepts and techniques

I have created application-according to my phone screen size(samsung galaxy ace) but I created all back ground images sizes appropriate for it..I do not know what will happen It insllaed in any other phone..sure it will distorted..So Please help me to modify my app for compatible with most of the devises.
Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can make a folder under "res" and make folders such as "layout-small", "layout-medium" etc to provide for multiple backgrounds.
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: Is there a way to create only one screen for all devices. Which Layout will work better in all screens?

Comment: @Nishant, I'm not too sure, because the problem is if you use one layout, and with the wide multitude range of devices, you'll run into a whole host of problems. It's better to have multiple layouts. If you want to try, I would reccomend layout-medium for handheld devices. If it is a problem though, you can always specify exactly which type of device you targeting in the AndroidManifest.XML file